# Problem with Cygwin

Tags: bash, authentication, cygwin, mount

Since few days, when I launch Cygwin, my bash window indicates:

```
bash-3.2$
```

Before I had:

```
name@XXX ~
#
```

Also, when I type `mount`, I see directories which are mounted but I don't see /bin or /usr/bin:

```
c: on /mnt/c type system (binmode,noumount)
d: on /mnt/d type system (binmode,noumount)
```

What I have done to have this and how can I return to my old Cygwin ? Thanks for your help.

PS: I have already try to re-install Cygwin. It doesn't change anything. I still have the same thing.

Comment: If you can say me what is wrong instead of downvote it would be nice.

Comment: I agree, many people down-vote without giving a reason. However, reading your post, it is not clear what the question is. Are you looking to have a) your prompt back, and b) /bin and /usr/bin back?

Comment: In fact, I thought the two questions were tied.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your prompt back, put this line in your ~/.bashrc:

```
PS1='\u@\h \w\n# '
export PS1
```

As for /bin and /usr directory, do they show up when you list the directory?

```
ls /
```

Answer (score 0):

The PS1 variable drives what is displayed on your prompt. You will need to add it to the .bashrc.

yours looks like it will be something like: `'\u@\h ~ '`

Check out this [article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) for a pretty cool breakdown of all the various things you can display